# PCA analysis with python pandas with many columns

Tags: python, pandas, pca

I have a .vcf file, where

```
column1 = chrom
column2 = pos
column3 = ID
column4 = reference
column5 = Alt
column6 = qual
column7 = filter
column8 = info
column9 = format    
column 10 - 99 = 100 columns that have a number of either zero or one
```

I read in the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
vcf=open('/Users/cmdb/Desktop/Lab6_GWAS/variants.vcf', 'r')
```

and have this that shouldnt be used

```
for line in vcf:
    fields=line.strip().split()
    A01=fields[9]
    A02=fields[10]
    A03=fields[11]
```

However, this would take way too long, because I want to save all those **zero** and **ones**, so I can run a PCA analysis through Python later on. PCA (principal component analysis). I would like to use `pandas` but not sure how I can do so for so many columns.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` doesn't have implemented PCA algorithms.

use [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) instead.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca.fit(df)
```

and get access to the components like this:

```
pca.components_
```